# Java 8 stream replace object in one array from another

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two arrays of objects. I want to update one array with updated objects from the second array if the object matches a certain criteria. For example, I have this:

```
public class Foobar
{
   private String name;

   // Other methods here...

   public String getName() { return this.name; }
}

Foobar [] original = new Foobar[8];
// Instantiate them here and set their field values

Foobar [] updated = new Foobar[8];
// Instantiate them here and set their field values

/* Use Java8 stream operation here
*   - Check if name is the same in both arrays
*   - Replace original Foobar at index with updated Foobar
*
*   Arrays.stream(original).filter(a -> ...)
*/
```

I know I can make a simple `for` loop to do this. I want to know if it's possible to do this using streams. I can't figure out what to put in `filter` or after that.

Comment: You must be specific on the criteria if you want some help.

Comment: Stream-based code for this is not going to be as clear or efficient as the straight-up traditional code for this operation.  _Don't bother._

Comment: You're right about the efficiency. It seems to run slower than the traditional for loop approach. However, I think the answer posted by Mureinik is pretty readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One neat trick you can use here is to create a stream of indexes and use them to evaluate the corresponding elements:

```
IntStream.range(0, original.length)
         .filter(i -> original[i].getName().equals(updated[i].getName()))
         .forEach(i -> original[i] = updated[i]);
```